# List view wrap content

Tags: android, listview

I have a dialog, that can be divided into three parts.

From TOP:

1. TEXT - that needs to be visible all the time
2. ListView - in the middle of the popup that shall be visible, and
   if not fit into screen, shall be scroll-able
3. BUTTONS (ok/cancel) - that needs to be visible all the time too

The thing I want is - that the 1st and 3rd part are visible all the time, and that the popup has smallest possible height. That means it all scales according to the middle part - to the list. I want the items so be seen, if it should not fir they have to be scrollable.

Here is a sketch:
(small and large list)
[image]
I dont know how to manage that, ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should use a Relative Layout as container of your popUp, and then you put your text and "bellow" your listView and finaly your 2 buttons

```
ArrayAdapter<String> lAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.act_puch){

        int lCalculedheight=0;
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View v= super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            lCalculedheight+=convertView.getMeasuredHeight();


            // This will calculate your height of listView and your popup will be adjusted automatically
            parent.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, lCalculedheight));
            return v;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanx! Worked like a charm!